# Hive Query to get US Federal Holidays

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I had the need to write a Hive SQL query to derive US Federal Holidays. I wrote the below query. Just wanted to check if there is a better/concise way of writing this with available Hive Functions. I checked SO and other online collab websites, but could not find any good solution based on Hive Functions.

For floating holidays which do not have a fixed day, I basically get the day of the week using the date_format('date','u') function and I check the possible days of the month for that holiday.

```sql
select 
dd.full_date,
case
    when month(dd.full_date) = 1 then
        case
        -- New Year
            when day(dd.full_date) = 1 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') in (1,2,3,4,5) then 'NEW_YEAR'
        -- If new year is a Saturday or Sunday, then I have used the immediate Monday as the holiday.
            when day(dd.full_date) = 2 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 1 then 'NEW_YEAR'
            when day(dd.full_date) = 3 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 1 then 'NEW_YEAR'
        -- MLK Day. 3rd Monday of January
            when day(dd.full_date) in (15,16,17,18,19,20,21) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 1 then 'MLK'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 2 then
        case
        -- President's Day. 3rd Monday of February
            when day(dd.full_date) in (15,16,17,18,19,20,21) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 1 then 'PRES_DAY' 
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 5 then
        case
        -- Memorial Day. Last Monday of May
            when day(dd.full_date) in (25,26,27,28,29,30,31) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 1 then 'MEMORIAL' 
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end     
    when month(dd.full_date) = 7 then
        case
        -- July 4th.
            when day(dd.full_date) = 4 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') in (1,2,3,4,5) then 'JULY_4'
        -- If July 4th is a Sunday then July 5th (Monday) is considered a holiday.
            when day(dd.full_date) = 5 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 1 then 'JULY_4'
        -- If July 4th is a Saturday then July 3rd (Friday) is considered a holiday.
            when day(dd.full_date) = 3 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 5 then 'JULY_4'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 9 then
        case
        -- Labor Day. First Monday of September
            when day(dd.full_date) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 1 then 'LABOR' 
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 10 then
        case
        -- Columbus Day. 2nd Monday of October
            when day(dd.full_date) in (8,9,10,11,12,13,14) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 1 then 'COLUMBUS_DAY' 
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 11 then
        case
        -- Thanksgiving. 4th Thursday of November
            when day(dd.full_date) in (22,23,24,25,26,27,28) and date_format(dd.full_date,'u') = 4 then 'THANKSGIVING' 
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) = 12 then
        case
        -- CHRISTMAS
            when day(dd.full_date) = 25 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') in (1,2,3,4,5) then 'CHRISTMAS'
        -- If 25th Dec is a Sunday
            when day(dd.full_date) = 26 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 1 then 'CHRISTMAS'
        -- If 25th Dec is a Saturday
            when day(dd.full_date) = 24 and date_format(dd.full_date ,'u') = 5 then 'CHRISTMAS'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
    when month(dd.full_date) in (3,4,6,8,10) then
        case
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (6) then 'WE_SAT'
            when date_format(dd.full_date,'u') in (7) then 'WE_SUN'
            else 'WD'
        end
end as us_federal_holiday
from date_dim dd
```

Comment: The full_date is a string of the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. This query works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to join to a table that contains all of the holidays?

Comment: @JimJimson I am writing this query to actually build a look-up table for several years, past and present, to run analytics on product usage around weekends and holidays.